# Kivy Instance of Button widget added to GridLayout missing pos value on creation?

Tags: python, button, widget, kivy

In my python/kivy code below, I try to create a new instance of `MainWindow` (which is a `GridLayout` with additional functionality) named `main`, populate it with Button widgets and return it in `MainApp.build()`.

I have added a `Debug` Button to print the `pos` value of all children of `main` when the button is pressed.

The other `Btn` Buttons will print `self.pos` when pressed.

Within the `build()` method, i print the positions of all children in `main` before returning `main`. It does show the full list of children, but gives [0,0] for all children's `pos` value.

However, there the `on_release()` method for the `Btn` Buttons give a correct `self.pos` value when called.

Is there a way to get the proper `pos` values for the children of `main` on initialization without having to call a method in the `Btn` class?

I suspect this has something to do with how `GridLayout` handles Widget positioning.

I have made `main` global for some other functionality in this project am I working on. I hope it isn't a huge problem other than the whole 'you shouldn't use global values' thing.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

class MainWindow(GridLayout): # main class
    def popbtns(self):
        i = 1
        while (i <= 29):
            self.add_widget(Btn(text='Btn #' + str(i) + ' at '+ str(self.pos)))
            i = i + 1

class Btn(Button): # button class
    def on_release(self):
        print('self.pos= ' + str(self.pos))

class Debug(Button): # debug button
    def on_release(self):
        for child in self.parent.children:
            print(str(child) + ' pos is ' + str(child.pos))

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):

        global main
        main = MainWindow(cols=7)
        # make background
        with main.canvas:
            Rectangle(pos=main.pos, size=Window.size)

        # populate gridlayout with Buttons
        main.add_widget(Debug(text='debug',background_color=(1,0,0,1)))
        main.popbtns() 
        # print position of buttons...
        for child in main.children:
            print(str(child) + ' pos is ' + str(child.pos))
        return main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read positions of the buttons before these buttons are even placed on the window. They are placed after the `build` function returns. To read these positions as soon as possible, you need a separate function, which will execute after a short delay. Use [Clock](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html) to achieve this:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
...
class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):

        main = MainWindow(cols=7)
        self.root = main  # don't use global!
        # make background
        with main.canvas:
            Rectangle(pos=main.pos, size=Window.size)

        # populate gridlayout with Buttons
        main.add_widget(Debug(text='debug', background_color=(1, 0, 0, 1)))
        main.popbtns()
        # print position of buttons...
        Clock.schedule_once(self.delayed_function, 0.1)            

    def delayed_function(self, dt):
        self.print_buttons_pos()

    def print_buttons_pos(self):
        for child in self.root.children:
            print(str(child) + ' pos is ' + str(child.pos))
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.